# Qual o melhor componente para redimensionar e particionar imagem em diferentes tamanhos?

Tags: css, html5, twitter-bootstrap

já procurei bastante e existem algumas soluções para fazer "resize" nas imagens e criar os "thumbnail" a partir de uma imagem original. Estou criando uma rede corporativa e gostaria de redimensionar uma imagem que o usuário faz o upload, e em seguida assim como em todas as redes, possibilitar recortes, em seguida criar vários "thumbnail" (miniaturas) em diferentes tamanhos.

Alguém tem uma dica de como fazer isso? Canvas do HTML 5? Bootstrap possui algum componente em jQuery que faça isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podemos fazer o recorte através do componente `jCrop`(http://jcrop.org/). Já o redimensionamento da imagem em vários outros tamanhos diferenciados podemos criá-la através da função nativa do PHP `imagecopyresized` (php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagecopyresized.php)